# UICollectionView not displaying cells and crashing application Xcode 10.0

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, constraints, sigabrt

I'm new to Xcode so apologies if I'm missing something obvious but I've been stuck on this for days now.

I've created a UICollectionView - [collection view in storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJJNP.png)

There are constraints in place 0 to each side of the view, and also one to the label above. The image and the label in the cell also have constraints.

when I run the application I get this - [Running application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7C9M.png)

I'm not sure how that is possible given the constraints. But If I remove any constraint, edit the existing ones, or remove them entirely I'm just getting a SIGABRT exception.

I'm extremely confused, if my code is compiling and running, I'm assuming that the code populating the UICollectionView is working. Is there something

TestVC.swift

```
import UIKit

class TestVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var myCollection: UICollectionView!

// making this an empty array incase the data hasn't loaded yet.
private(set) public var testArrays = [dataArrays]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myCollection.dataSource = self
    myCollection.delegate = self

}

func initData(category: Category){

    testArrays = DataService.instance.testData(forCategoryTitle: category.title)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return testArrays.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as? collectionViewCell{

        let testArray = testArrays[indexPath.row]
        cell.updateViews(testArray: testArray)
        return cell

    }

    return collectionViewCell()
}
}
```

collectionViewCell.swift

```
import UIKit

class collectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var cellImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cellLabel: UILabel!


    func updateViews(dataarray: dataArrays) {
        cellImage.image = UIImage(named: dataarray.imageName)
        cellLabel.text = dataarray.title

    }
}
```

Comment: how do you add cell to UICollectionView? Do you have extra xib file?

Comment: Yep another view file handles that, I've added that to the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cell itself wasn't registered in the Attributes Inspector, I changed it to -  collectionViewCell and now it's working.

I also has an issue with constraints, I wasn't reading the Output terminal entirely, being new to this it all looked a bit cryptic but I was able to troubleshoot through the output.

This was very helpful
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/219/